# FLEX: Make LineChart DATATIP constrain to vertical axis

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, charts, linechart

When making a line chart, Lets say its for business sales for different depts and horizontally is days and vertically is dollars. When you hover over a line it tells a dataTip tells you the sales for that dept. on that day. I want it to show all the depts at the same time, so say you hover over day 3, I want the dataTips for all depts on day 3 to display so you can compare the values for all the sales on the same day. I set the mouseSensitivity for the dataTips to display all the lines at once but I end up getting day 2 for one dept and day 3 for another which is not wanted. This is actually posted as a bug and explained better here: http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FLEXDMV-1853

I am wondering if anyone can come up with a work-around for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem to this recently and came up with a solution that also applies to your problem. I had a step LineChart and wanted to display a data tip when the user hovered anywhere on the line instead of just at defined data points.

You can read about the solution I wrote for that problem here: [Flex: Customizing data tip location and behavior in a LineChart](http://instantdelay.com/2010/08/flex-customizing-data-tip-location-and-behavior-in-a-linechart/)

You'll have to modify my solution slightly to fit your problem:

On line 47 you can remove the `Math.abs(last.y - mouseLoc.y) < 50` check. This constrains the data tips to lines that are within 50 pixels vertically of the mouse.

I'm assuming that you're using the default *segment* line chart which just draws lines directly between data points. You'll need to modify the code that calculates the line value at a given x-coordinate to work with that chart type. I already find the closest data point to the left of the mouse with lines 33-41 and store it in `last`. Just get the next data point (which will be the one closest to the *right* of the mouse) and use something like this to get the value at the mouse:

```
var slope:Number = (nextPoint.y - last.y) / (nextPoint.x - last.x);
var lineYAtMouse:Number = (slope * (last.x - mouseLoc.x)) + last.y;
var lineValue:Array = line.localToData(new Point(mouseLoc.x, lineYAtMouse));
```

Then replace lines 69 through 72 with:

```
hitPoint.x = mouseLoc.x;
hitPoint.y = lineYAtMouse;
hitPoint.xValue = lineValue[0];
hitPoint.yValue = lineValue[1];
```

I haven't tested these modifications so there could be a bug or 2 but the general idea is there. I hope maybe this is still useful to someone. This question is getting pretty old. :)

Comment: Site is down. Here's the archived version. http://web.archive.org/web/20120623212953/http://instantdelay.com/2010/08/flex-customizing-data-tip-location-and-behavior-in-a-linechart

Comment: @deshko Oops, messed up my hosting. Should be back now.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but a poor alternative:

You could create your own DataTip renderer that [ahem] mapped the location of every point and drew the tip for each one there.

Basically, you would be duplicating a lot of the code inside the charting classes.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but working on column charts. Was thinking that I could enable the vertical gridLines using backgroundElements and then add a chart event listener for mouse over (which fires when mouse passes over a vertical gridline). Using the localX value, i could compare it to the closest datapoint, maybe.

Brian